# If "std::cin" 's input was incorrect then it will crash but the rest of program will work

Tags: c++

Like the code below :

```
int count = 0;
std::cin >> count_of_emploies;
for (int i = 0; i < 11 && (count <= 1 || count >= 100); i++) {
    std::cout << "enter again.";
    std::cin >> count;
    if (i > 9) return 0;
}
```

but when input was like "asdf" this code causes all the std::cin crush and the other part of the program almost work but without waiting for user's input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when input was like "asdf" this code causes all the std::cin crush

That's because a "bad" input is received.
To ignore this and continue, you will have to

a) clear the stream error flags `std::cin.clear()`

b) ignore the maximum possible characters in input buffer, until a newline using `std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');`